# File Download link with Angularjs and SpringMVC

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, jsp, spring-mvc

Is it possible to provide a link to download the file in a webpage where when clicked the call goes to an angularjs controller?

I gave ng-click method for the download link in my jsp page which goes straight to my angularjs controller.

```
<div><h7><a href='' ng-click="downloadfile()">Click here to download as CSVfile</a></h7></div>
```

And my angularjs method is as follows:

```
$scope.downloadfile = function(){
            _$asyncpost.getData({
                url : '/downloadcsv'
            });
        }
```

This method url is mapped to my java controller url and the method is called where the needed data is stored in a StringBuffer which is then flushed to the HttpServletResponse. The java method is working fine. But when clicked on the download link it just only excutes java method till end and stops without showing the pop-up for saving. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You could set the `href` of `<a>` element to file path, use `download` attribute

Comment: so using angularjs wont work?

Comment: Have not tried `angularjs`. If browser supports `download` attribute http://caniuse.com/#feat=download you can achieve same result

Comment: But I need to get some data from another method in angularjs..Also the architecture is angularjs based, so im insisted to follow that method. Is there anyway to achieve it with angular in between.

Comment: You can using `Blob` or `File` object with `type` set to `"application/octet-stream"`, `URL.createObjectURL()`, `window.open()` to provide client file for download